# $\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}(\omega)$ is right continuous and has left hand limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given random variables $\xi_1, \xi_2, \dots$ on a probability space, with partial sums $S_n = \xi_1 + \cdots + \xi_n$, let $X^n(\omega)$ be the function in the space of cadlag functions with value 
$$X_t^n(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}(\omega).$$

How can we prove that this is a cadlag function for fixed $\omega$? Also is it right continuous and has left hand limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers the function $f(t)=a_{[nt]}$ is cadlag. This is easy to verify from the definition of  $[x]$.

Proof: Let $t_j$ decrease to $t$. Then $nt_j$ decrease to $nt$. If $k \leq nt <k+1$ then $k \leq nt_j < k+1$ for all $j$ sufficiently large so $[nt_j]=[nt]$ and $a_{[nt_j]} =a_{[nt]}$ for all $j$ sufficiently large. This proves right continuity. I leave the existence of left limits to you.

Comment: Is $[x]$ the floor of $x$? Could you give me more hints as to why $f(t)$ is cadlag?

Comment: Yes, $[x]$ is the floor function. I have included a proof of right-continuity.

Comment: Could you help me with the existence of left limits? I'm not sure how to show that for every sequence $t_j$ converging to $t$ from the left, we $f(t_j)$ converges to the same limit.

Comment: Hint: if $y_j$ increases to $y$ then $[y_j]$ need not tend to $[y]$ (example: $y_j=1-\frac 1 j, y=1$) but certainly $lim [y_j]$ exists. The limit is either $[y]$ or $[y]-1$.